# Error sending data using intent from class to MainActivity

Tags: android

In my MainActivity I need to know the state of a boolean type variable to hide or put an icon visible, but this variable is generated in another class called TcpClient which is called several times by the MainActivity, I am trying to use intent to send this variable from the TcpClient class but I have errors.

This is my code of my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private TcpClient mTcpClient;
public boolean statusWIFI = false;
.
.
public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {
    @Override
    protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {
        mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {           //we create a TCPClient object and
                publishProgress(message);                   //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //arrayList.add("RX: " + values[0]);                 //in the 
    arrayList we add the messaged received from server
        mDumpTextView.append( values[0] );
        mDumpTextView.append( "\n" );
        mScrollView.smoothScrollTo( 0, mDumpTextView.getBottom() );

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                   // notify the 
    adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message 
    received
        // from server was added to the list
    }
```

}

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

MenuItem IconWIFI = menu.findItem(R.id.bt1_wifi);

Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = null;
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

if (bundle !=null) {
    statusWIFI = bundle.getBoolean( "mstatusWIFI");
}

if (statusWIFI == true){
    IconUsbON.setVisible(true);
}else{
    IconUsbON.setVisible(false);
}

return true;
}
```

This is the code of my TcpClient class:

```
public class TcpClient {
private Boolean statusWIFIX = false;
.
.
public void stopClient() {

statusWIFIX = false;
Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
intent.putExtra( "mstatusWIFI", statusWIFIX );
startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );

sendMessage(Constants.CLOSED_CONNECTION+": " + Modelox);                
// send message that we are closing the connection
mRun = false;
if (mBufferOut != null) {
    mBufferOut.flush();
    mBufferOut.close();
}
mMessageListener = null;
mBufferIn = null;
mBufferOut = null;
mServerMessage = null;
}
```

Here is the error; someone could tell me how to correct this

[image]

Comment: Is the `TcpClient` class another `java.class` or you have declared into the `MainActivity.class`.
Because you are having problem with the `this.startActivity` ?

Comment: which variable value you want to access?

Comment: The TcpClient class is another  java.class, I want to access to statusWIFIX

Comment: @W1ll check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I did't see any initialization of `mTcpClient`, you need to initialize it like:

```
mTcpClient= TcpClient();
```

and if your variable is in TcpClient class you can access it via `mTcpClient.statusWIFIX`

You also need to make statusWIFIX scope to public like this:

```
public Boolean statusWIFIX = false;
```

in your `TcpClient` class.

You can also send data via intent but just for accessing statusWIFIX to start an activity again is not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to pass activity context into the Intent constructor. The TCPClient is not seems any activity or service.

Comment: Its a comment more than an answer. Also you have enough reputation to add comments